# Emulate and/or Enable Single Sign On in Tomcat using AJP

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, authentication

I have apache forwarding requests to tomcat using ajp. My app in tomcat uses basic authentication via tomcat-users user database.  Users are listed there, given roles, and everything works great.

However, my users have id cards they plug into their workstations which identify them by a unique number.  I don't know the details of this, but apache and the browser has some module(s) which automatically identifies the user and essentially authenticates her and REMOTE_USER is available when in the apache environment.

Unfortunately, REMOTE_USER isn't available in tomcat (via the request.getRemoteUser()), so the user is prompted to log in when going to my tomcat app. I found this thread:

[Forward REMOTE_USER to tomcat via AJP (e.g. for shibboleth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749065/forward-remote-user-to-tomcat-via-ajp-e-g-for-shibboleth)

Which describes that you can disable tomcat authentication, which makes the REMOTE_USER available in tomcat, but since we've disabled the tomcat authentication, there are no longer any roles assigned to the user.

To be clear, I've added this id number to the tomcat-users but it doesn't help:

```
<user username="billg" password="pass" roles="ceo"/>
<!-- billg's id number -->
<user username="12345@ms" roles="ceo"/>
```

I know this is a somewhat unique environment and request, but does anyone have experience with making something like this work?

FWIW: This is apache 2.2+ and tomcat 6 (but if there's a solution for tomcat 7+ I'm interested in that as well).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to set `tomcatAuthentication="false"` in your `server.xml`'s AJP `<Connector>` configuration.

See [Tomcat's AJP Connector Configuration Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/ajp.html) for reference.

While the reference I gave was for Tomcat 8, the same technique also applies to Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 6 as well. But you may as well upgrade to Tomcat 8 since it's stable and Tomcat 6 is in maintenance mode these days and doesn't get much in the way of improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you follow the link I gave you'll see that is the suggestion. I tried this and it works, where the remote user is available, however the the roles are not available for the user. I'm trying to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to fetch the roles yourself; httpd cannot provide them. You might want to write a `Filter` that grabs the `REMOTE_USER` as a trusted identity and then load the roles from wherever they are stored (e.g. RDBMS, LDAP, etc.) and wrap the request such that `request.isUserInRole` then works with your application. If you need to use container-managed authorization, you'll need a `Valve` instead of a `Filter` because Tomcat's authorization checks happen before any `Filter`s are invoked.

Comment: @Christopher_Schultz: Thanks for the response and this makes a little more sense. Do you by any chance have any guidance on how to do this, or should I just consult the tomcat documentation?

Comment: Join the [Tomcat users mailing list](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) and ask for help. ;)